# Getting error for not providing complete options values in url

Tags: javascript, node.js

My program is throwing error for not providing all the values to the options in URL. I have to comment other options if I'm passing only one value in url
My code

```
    taskRouter.get('/tasks', auth, async (req, res) => {
try {        
    await req.user.populate({
        path: 'tasks',
        match: {
            completed: (req.query.completed === 'true')
        },
        options: {
            limit: parseInt(req.query.limit),
            skip: parseInt(req.query.skip),
            sort: {
                createdAt: -1
            }
        }
    });
    res.send(req.user.tasks)
} catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send()
}
```

})

I'm passing following command in postman
url: {{url}}/tasks?limit=3

Either I have to provide value to all the options defined in program or I have to comment those options whose value I'm not going to provide in url.

Comment: You are using `req.query.skip` in your code but didn't specify `skip` in query string.

Comment: That's exactly my question, Why do i have to give all the values in url. Can't it consider them zero automatically ??

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using ORM you will have to validate req.query manually:

```
taskRouter.get('/tasks', auth, async (req, res) => {
try {
    await req.user.populate({
        path: 'tasks',
        match: {
            completed: (req.query.completed === 'true')
        },
        options: {
            limit: parseInt(req.query.limit),
            skip: parseInt(req.query.skip ? req.query.skip : 0),
            sort: {
                createdAt: -1
            }
        }
    });
    res.send(req.user.tasks)
} catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send()
}
```

Comment: means i've to make them zero using some other ways if i'm not passing their respective values. Thanks

Comment: You can set them `null` or `undefined`, too whichever doesn't trigger an error.